# Field from advanced custom field returns null

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom fields and i have made 2 custom field types one matches where a get all the matches and i use some custom fields here and one called predictions which i want to display them in front page using the followin query

```
<?php
        $headlines = 0;
        $headlines_lead =  get_field('sixed_relationship','alpha_brief', false);
        $args = array(
                'posts_per_page'    => 4,
                'offset'            => 0,
                'post_type'         => array('analysis_stoiximatos', 'printed_post'),
                'post__in'          => $headlines_lead,
                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                'orderby'           => 'post__in'
               
                );
        ?>

        <?php $banner_query2 = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
        
    
<?php 
   
    
?>


<div class="central_main_area">

<h1>matches </h1>

<?php
    $entos_edras_omada = get_field('entos_edras_omada');

    

?>
<?php if( $banner_query2->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while ( $banner_query2->have_posts() ) : $banner_query2->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    

                    <?php the_title();
                            setup_postdata( $args );

                    global $post;
                    
                    var_dump(the_field( 'entos_edras_omada', get_the_id() ));

                    ?>
                    

                    
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<section class="oloi_oi_agones" id="oloi_oi_agones">


</section>
```

the problen is that i get the title of each match BUT the field returns null....

Comment: What do you get when you var_dump `get_fields()` for each post? Do you see your fields available?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to setup_postdata when you're within the loop. I'm not sure that I understand `$headlines_lead =  get_field('sixed_relationship','alpha_brief', false);` This looks incorrect to me. What kind of field is this? I'm guessing a relationship field and you're trying to get an array output of post IDs, correct?

Try this:

```
<?php
$headlines = 0;

$headlines_lead =  get_field('sixed_relationship', false, false);

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 4,
    'offset'            => 0,
    'post_type'         => array('analysis_stoiximatos', 'printed_post'),
    'post__in'          => $headlines_lead,
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'orderby'           => 'post__in'
);

$banner_query2 = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<div class="central_main_area">
    <h1>matches </h1>

    <?php
    if( $banner_query2->have_posts() ):
        ?>
        <ul>
            <?php
            while ( $banner_query2->have_posts() ) : $banner_query2->the_post();
                ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php
                        the_title();
                        var_dump(the_field( 'entos_edras_omada', get_the_id() ));
                        ?>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is relationship custom fields it needs another loop inside

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
                    //echo $post_id;
                    // $entos_edras_omada = get_field('entos_edras_omada',$post_id); 
                    //$dish_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_entos_edras_omada', true );
                    //echo $dish_meta;
                    //echo $entos_edras_omada;
                    ?>
                    <?php
                        $featured_posts = get_field('locations');
                        if( $featured_posts ): ?>
                            <?php foreach( $featured_posts as $post ): 

                                // Setup this post for WP functions (variable must be named $post).
                                setup_postdata($post); ?>
                                
                                    <span><?php the_field( 'entos_edras_omada' ); ?></span>
                                    
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <?php 
                            // Reset the global post object so that the rest of the page works correctly.
                            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
```